# Drop Down Menu with scrollable Menu. Cant fix

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, scroll

I'm trying to make a drop down menu with scrollable sub-menus?
I've gone through https://css-tricks.com/long-dropdowns-solution/ but is doesn't work.

I'm wondering if anyone can help, i have been trying to use 
max-height and overflow but they just cancel out the sun menu appearing.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I've gone through every  tutorial i can find with no luck.

In a perfect world once the user hovers over tips & tricks, a new menu appears (as it does) with the ability to have an endless scrollable menu within so I'm not restricted.

Any help appreciated

```css
#wrap {
 width: 150px; 
 height: 50px; 
    padding-bottom: 10px;
 margin: 0; /* Ensures there is no space between sides of the screen and the menu */
 z-index: 1; /* Makes sure that your menu remains on top of other page elements */
 position: fixed;
 background-color: #FAFAFA;
    
 }
.navbar {
     margin-top:-2px;
 height: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
 margin: 0;
 position: fixed; /* Ensures that the menu doesn’t affect other elements */
 border-right: 1px solid #FAFAFA; 
    z-index: 12;
 }
.navbar li  {
            padding-bottom: 10px;
   height: auto;
   width: 150px;  /* Each menu item is 150px wide */
   /*float: left;   This lines up the menu items horizontally */
            object-position: top;
   text-align: center;  /* All text is placed in the center of the box */
   list-style: none;  /* Removes the default styling (bullets) for the list */
   font: normal bold 12px/1.2em Arial, Verdana, Helvetica;  
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   background-color: #FAFAFA;
    
                        }
.navbar a {       
  padding: 18px 0;  /* Adds a padding on the top and bottom so the text appears centered vertically */ /* Creates a border in a slightly lighter shade of blue than the background.  Combined with the right border, this creates a nice effect. */
  border-right: 1px solid #000; /* Creates a border in a slightly darker shade of blue than the background.  Combined with the left border, this creates a nice effect. */
  text-decoration: none;  /* Removes the default hyperlink styling. */
  color: #FC4C02; /* Text color is black */
  display: block;
        margin-top: 0px;
  }

.navbar li:hover, a:hover {
    
    background-color: #E7E7E7;
    
}
       

.navbar li ul  {
    list-style:none;
  display: none; /* Hides the drop-down menu */         
  margin: 0; /* Aligns drop-down box underneath the menu item */
  padding: 0; /* Aligns drop-down box underneath the menu item */  
        margin-left:150px;
        float:left;
        margin-top: -48px;
        height:0px;
    
        
  }    

.navbar li:hover ul  
        {
        display: block; /* Displays the drop-down box when the menu item is hovered over */
        z-index: 12;
        padding-left: 0px;
            
        
        }

.navbar li ul li {
    background-color: #E7E7E7;
}

.navbar li ul li a  
        {
        margin-top: -2px;
        bottom: .5px solid #FC4C02;
        z-index: 1001;
  }

.navbar li ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #FAFAFA;

}
```

```html
 

   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p style="margin-left:10px; font-size: 80%"><a href=""></a></p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div id="wrap" style="margin-top:0px; margin-left:-5px;">
                    <ul class="navbar">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Tips & Tricks</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="">gg</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="">aa</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="">pp</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="">ll</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="">qqe</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">News</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="">news</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="">Market</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="">Example 3</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="">Example 4</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are looking for this:

```css
#wrap {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin: 0;  /* Ensures there is no space between sides of the screen and the menu */
  z-index: 1;  /* Makes sure that your menu remains on top of other page elements */
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
}
.navbar {
  margin-top: -2px;
  height: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  position: fixed;  /* Ensures that the menu doesn’t affect other elements */
  border-right: 1px solid #FAFAFA;
  z-index: 12;
}
.navbar li {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  height: auto;
  width: 150px;  /* Each menu item is 150px wide */
  /*float: left;   This lines up the menu items horizontally */
  object-position: top;
  text-align: center;
  /* All text is placed in the center of the box */
  list-style: none;
  /* Removes the default styling (bullets) for the list */
  font: normal bold 12px/1.2em Arial, Verdana, Helvetica;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
}
.navbar a {
  padding: 18px 0;  /* Adds a padding on the top and bottom so the text appears centered vertically */

  /* Creates a border in a slightly lighter shade of blue than the background.  Combined with the right border, this creates a nice effect. */
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  /* Creates a border in a slightly darker shade of blue than the background.  Combined with the left border, this creates a nice effect. */
  text-decoration: none;
  /* Removes the default hyperlink styling. */
  color: #FC4C02;
  /* Text color is black */
  display: block;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.navbar li:hover,
a:hover {
  background-color: #E7E7E7;
}
.navbar li ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: none;
  /* Hides the drop-down menu */
  margin: 0;
  /* Aligns drop-down box underneath the menu item */
  padding: 0;
  /* Aligns drop-down box underneath the menu item */
  margin-left: 150px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: -48px;
  
  /* CHANGES ARE BELOW HERE */
  
  overflow-y: auto; 
  overflow-x: hidden;
  max-height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
}
.navbar li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  /* Displays the drop-down box when the menu item is hovered over */
  z-index: 12;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
.navbar li ul li {
  background-color: #E7E7E7;
}
.navbar li ul li a {
  margin-top: -2px;
  bottom: .5px solid #FC4C02;
  z-index: 1001;
}
.navbar li ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p style="margin-left:10px; font-size: 80%">
          <a href=""></a>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="wrap" style="margin-top:0px; margin-left:-5px;">
          <ul class="navbar">
            <li>
              <a href="#">Tips & Tricks</a>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="">gg</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="">aa</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="">pp</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="">ll</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="">qqe</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">News</a>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="">news</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="">Market</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="">Example 3</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="">Example 4</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I've been playing around with this and I've tried alot. No idea why it wasn't working earlier.  Thanks, really appreciate it.

Comment: Glad that it helped you!